# How improve armature in blender in a character

Tags: armature

I was trying to move the mesh using armature but the result is terrible, I think I create an armature wrong but I don't know how to make changes.

Have you some ideas? I think the food's bones are wrong but I don't know how.

Also, I would like to dress the character, it is best to do it before changing pose or after?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all apply the scale of the armature, select the mesh in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance* because you may have overlapping vertices, and also recalculate the normals of your mesh as it looks like you have inverted normals:

[image]

It looks like these vertices are not assigned to any vertex group, so they can't be influenced by any bone, you need to make some corrections in *Weight Paint* mode: Switch to *Solid* mode and to *Object* mode, enable the armature *In Front* option in the *Object panel > Viewport Display*, select the armature, shift select the character object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select a bone with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click and paint:

[image]

Comment: exactly the same way, except you need to select other bones